# How to assign weights (or modifier values) for modifiable number of input size in Ms Excel 2013?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm currently building a`Decision Support System` with `Ms. Excel 2013` for educational purposes.

In that program I have 9 inputs for the users to fill in order of priority. At the start I assumed that the users should fill all the entries. So I made the weight distribution arbitrarily.

That prototype worked without any technical problem. Then I was required to modify the program so that the users only have 1 mandatory entry. They are only required to choose the first entry then they can choose the subsequent entries or just leave them empty.

That of course comes at a price. If I want to do it manually, I need to create 9 sets of weight distributions then create a nested if to check the total entry number and pair it with the correct set.

I tried using `(n^2+n)/2` manually to have 9 sets or weights like here:
[image: this picture]

The program UI goes like this:
[image: this]

The idea is switching to the right set of weights according to the number of input from the UI.

Aside from doing manually like I did before, would there be a simpler solution?

Comment: Can you show us what you already have to help explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It's just that I don't know how to do that properly. For the time being I uploaded 2 screenshots. I hope those pictures help to explain.